# InlineQuery и mp3 файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Делаю бота на telebot и работаю с inline query.
Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки выходила песня...

Всё что я нашёл в оф. документации тг: `InlineQueryResultAudio`, но проблема в том, что мне нужно слать именно файлом.
Также пытался при `InlineQueryResultArticle` изменять в `input_message_content` это: `InputTextMessageContent` на это: `InputMediaAudio`.

Это не то что бы не работало, но мне выходила ошибка 400, с текстом:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse inline query result: Input message content is not specified"
```

Что делать? В доках telebot-а я всё таки не нашёл ничего полезного...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Первый](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultaudio) способ - отправка трека по ссылке

Для этого случая требуется указать валидную ссылку на аудиофайл.

Если перейти по такой ссылке, то в вашем браузере должен отображаться проигрыватель наподобие такого:

[image: 2]

Приведу простой пример, когда `handler` срабатывает при любом вводе текста.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.inline_handler(func=lambda query: len(query.query) > 0)
def query_text(query):
    inline_btn = types.InlineQueryResultAudio(
                id='1', # уникальный идентификатор
                audio_url='', # ваша ссылка на аудиофайл
                title='Eisenmann', 
                performer='Unheilig'
                ) 
    bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, [inline_btn])

    
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

## [Второй](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultcachedaudio) способ - отправка уже сохранённого на серверах Telegram аудиофайла

Здесь еще проще. Достаточно передать уникальный `id`, и `audio_file_id`.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['audio'])
def start(message):
    print(message.audio.file_id) # для получения audio_file_id аудиозаписи



@bot.inline_handler(func=lambda query: len(query.query) > 0)
def query_text(query):
    inline_btn = types.InlineQueryResultCachedAudio(
                id='1', 
                audio_file_id='', # валидный file_id аудиофайла
                ) 
    bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, [inline_btn])


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: 4]